# NestJs deploy on heroku failure

Tags: heroku, deployment, nestjs

Getting below error on git push heroku master

sh: 1: nest: not found
-----> Build failed

```
   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
   
   If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
   https://help.heroku.com/
   
   Love,
   Heroku
```

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
!     Push failed

Comment: I'm not an expert on NestJS, but shouldn't `nest` only be used in development? I suspect you just need to build your application (specify an appropriate build command in your `package.json`) and tell Heroku to run the compiled JavaScript (either via a `Procfile` or the start command in your `package.json`).

Comment: Can you show us the logs from heroku please ? Do you have the procfile file in your root directory ?